# Trying to assign a constant a value in a php class results in unexpected T_variable

Tags: php, syntax-error, constants

What's wrong in my code here?

```
<?php
class someClass
{ 

  const HOSTNAME = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; // p.s: this is line # 5
```

and basically when an object of this class is instantiated, I get this:
**syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/html/..../someClass.php on line 5**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php): (emphasis mine)

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) **a variable**,
>   a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.